# Aligning arrow lines in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have been working with draw.io (or diagrams.net) for a while now and one thing I can't seem to get right is line alignment. I am making a flow chart with block connected by arrows. The arrows snap to a grid, which is something I want. However, different arrows snap to different grid locations, which makes it look messy. With shapes you can align them with Arrange, but this does not work with lines.
The figure shows an example where I try to align the left arrow with the middle arrow. The left arrow can only snap just above and a bit under the middle arrow. Is there a way to overcome this? I do like the snapping, it just has to be on the same grid.
[image: arrow snapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do like the snapping, it just has to be on the same grid.

You can disable snapping temporarily by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you drag the line to position it more precisely.

Before

[image]

After

[image]